# C++ - Spades - Classes: How to use them

Tags: c++, class, struct

I'm trying to  learn about using Classes for this game of Spades project for school. I seem to be hitting all kinds of errors when running this code (below). I'm trying to create a card, create a deck, shuffle that deck, and then deal the cards to the player and computer. I'm not very certain that I'm uses classes correctly and I'm not sure how to implement them in the main() part yet. Any examples would be really helpful and appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <Windows.h>

// Game Specific Files
#include "CardGameConfig.h"
#include "CardGameFunctions.h"
#include "CardGameStructs.h"

using namespace std;



// Card Class
class Card
{
private:
    int _suit;
    int _rank;
public:
   Card();
   Card(int &iSuit, int &iRank); 
   ~Card(); // Deconstructor
   int GetSuit(); //Method
   int GetRank(); //Method
};


// sets a blank card
Card::Card(){      
    _suit = 0;
    _rank = 0;
}


// creates a card with a given suit
Card::Card(int &iSuit, int &iRank){
    _suit = iSuit;
    _rank = iRank;

} // end of Card function (class member)

int Card::GetSuit(){
        return _suit;
}

int Card::GetRank(){
    return _rank;
}

Card::~Card(){
}


// Deck Class
class Deck
{
private:
    Card cards[TOTAL_CARDS_IN_DECK];
    Card *_pCardList[52];
public:
    Deck();
   ~Deck();
   void Shuffle();
   Card DrawCard();
   Card *_pCardList; // holds an array of cards (52 of them)
   int _index;
};

Deck::Deck(){


    // Start deck index at zero
    _index = 0;
    _pCardList = new Card[TOTAL_CARDS_IN_DECK];

    // TOTAL_CARDS_IN_SUIT = 13
    for(int iRank = 0; iRank < TOTAL_CARDS_IN_SUIT; iRank++)
    {
        int iRankOffset = 2;
        iRank = iRank + iRankOffset;

        //TOTAL_SUITS = 4
        for(int iSuit = 0; iSuit < TOTAL_SUITS; iSuit++){
            iSuit = ESuits(iSuit);
            _pCardList[_index] = Card(iRank, iSuit);        
            _index++;
        } // end of iSuit for loop
    } // end of iRank for loop */
}


void Deck::Shuffle(){
    srand((int) time( NULL ) );

    for(int iCardNum = 0; iCardNum < TOTAL_CARDS_IN_DECK; iCardNum++)
    {
        int iRandomNumber = ( rand() % TOTAL_CARDS_IN_DECK-1);
        Card card = _pCardList[iCardNum];
        _pCardList[iCardNum] = _pCardList[iRandomNumber];
        _pCardList[iRandomNumber] = card;
    }
}

Card Deck::DrawCard(){

    _index++;
    return _pCardList[_index-1];

}

Deck::~Deck()
{
    delete [] cards;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    Card CardGame;
    Deck Deck;



//  cout << Deck._pCardList[1].GetRank() << " " << Deck._pCardList[1].GetSuit() <<     endl;

    return 0;
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Where are `TOTAL_CARDS_IN_DECK`, `TOTAL_CARDS_IN_SUIT` and other globals defined?

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare `_pCardList` twice:

```
class Deck {
private:
    Card cards[TOTAL_CARDS_IN_DECK];
    // Card *_pCardList[52]; // FIRST TIME (useless)
    Card *_pCardList;         // SECOND TIME (this should be private)
    int _index;               // This should also be private
public:
    Deck();
    ~Deck();
    void Shuffle();
    Card DrawCard();
};
```

Little bonus: for your drawfunction, you can do this:

```
Card Deck::DrawCard(){
    return _pCardList[_index++];
}
```

This works because `_index++` returns the value of `_index` **before** incrementing it.

Comment: If I just take _pCardList out and use "cards", since both holds an array of 52 elements, can I do this:
`code`
    Card Deck::DrawCard(){
        return cards[_index++];
    }